# Can getters and setters be mocked using mockito-flex?

Tags: apache-flex, mockito, setter, getter

Need to know if Mockito-flex supports mocking getters and setters.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Getters and setters can be mocked as long as the class being mocked and the getter/setter methods are non-final.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's an example:

```
 _mockFixedList = mock(IFixedList);
var len:int = 10;
given(_mockFixedList.length).willReturn(len);
```

Where IFixedList has

```
function get length():int;
```

Then

```
trace('len=' + len);
```

will trace 'len='+10;